# Who or what leads Stack Overflow's policy regarding posts?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, rules

I recently found [this post](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/) where it is stated that

> (...) SO is not interested in users getting answers to their
>   questions. Usually Q&A sites want their questioners to be happy, but
>   not SO. SO wants great questions and great answers (...)

and

> (...) Today your chances to get a useful answer to your question on SO
>   are close to zero. Instead you get a lot of comments arguing for
>   example that your question does not fit SO or wrongly worded or else
>   and nothing useful (...)

So I was wondering

- Who or what leads Stack Overflow's policy system?
- Do these policies change over time, are they revised/updated?
- If so, how are posts that were deleted (or any other) by not fulfilling the policies of SO treated?

Comment: Bear in mind that that post was written over four years ago, and has been discussed widely on Meta already.

Comment: Again, it's probably safe to ignore someone who uses the phrase "Nazi retards" in a blog post.

Comment: @BradLarson, yes, I agree with you completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Who or what lead Stackoverflow's policy system?

The community here on meta, and on the Stack Exchange meta. We all make policy collectively. Users propose policy changes and we all come together and discuss and vote on these changes.

> Do these policies change any time, are they revised/updated?

These policies are always changing and evolving as new cases are evaluated. Things that we once thought were cut and dry are proven to not be so, and the policies are revisited to address this.

To change the policies, one needs to change the minds of the users and contributors who make this site as great as it is. This usually means having some skin in the game.

> If so, how are treated posts which were deleted (or any other) by not fulfilling the policies of SO?

Very rarely are posts that are deleted because they didn't fit the policies at one point in the sites history undeleted due to the policies changing. There's just too much content for that to scale.

Comment: I didn't even bother addressing the mention of that blog post because it has already been discussed to death, resurrected, then discussed to death again so many times that it isn't even worth the effort to think about it anymore.

Comment: To note, while the community can drive discussion, even having a request with hundreds of votes will not in itself change policy. Only employees can make large policy decisions with regards to posting, especially with regards to close reasons and closure in general.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, SO rules come from these places with *very roughly* this priority:

1. Basic site design and goals.

   As SO was designed from the very first with answer quality and reusability in mind, the first quote is part of the site's DNA and really is not very likely to change much. It's the chosen strategy.
2. Official company declarations.

   For example, the [Summer of Love](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/). These aren't common, but do come around every year or two, perhaps.
3. Supported decisions by elected ♦ mods, or well-supported community consensus.

   Mostly expressed by meta posts with lots of upvotes and little robust counterargument, this is always open to possible changes, although on some topics the possibility is very low, as everything has been hashed out to exhaustion years ago. There's usually a fair number that shift a bit in any given year.
4. Emergent community tendencies.

   Naturally, some of the site's workings are just because lots of visible people are taking those actions, so others mimic them without any formal agreement. This is in constant low-level flux by the nature of things.

SO's standards generally have not lowered in much of a deliberate way, so there's little point in digging through old deleted posts (which are non-trivial to find anyway) in hopes of finding something that would now be acceptable. Rather, the vast majority of moderation is focused on *current* posts, with a small amount of attention paid to specific older posts that happen to appear for one reason or another.

Comment: The summer of love isn't really a change in policy though ("be nice" wasn't new, the post was merely emphasizing the importance of an existing policy).  A better example would be something like the change in what the close reasons are, or changes to the flag dialogs (most of these are just different wordings without changing what merits flagging, but some have been more than just clarifications).

Answer (score 4):

> Who or what leads Stack Overflow's policy system?

You do. And other users. And moderators. And CM's. All post on meta.

> Do these policies change over time, are they revised/updated?

Yes, they are revised and updated based on feedback from the meta-crowd

> If so, how are posts that were deleted (or any other) by not fulfilling the policies of SO treated?

Posts get deleted by

- voting from users with more that 10K reputation.
- by a moderator if such post is flagged and the reason to delete it is warranted.
- by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) if the post didn't get votes.

In all cases the post is only soft-deleted so in case anyone makes an error, these posts can be undeleted, if needed via a post on meta.